# If two file pointers point to the same file, is closing one of them enough?

Tags: c, file, file-pointer

If I have two file pointers and do the following:

```
FILE *f1,*f2;
f1= fopen("inputfile","r+");
f2=f1;
fclose(f2);
```

Is the equal operation valid, if it is, will the last line close f1 as well?

Comment: If you are *on* Linux then open file twice in f1 and f2.

Comment: You aren't closing the pointer, you're closing the object that the pointer points to.

Comment: btw its is quite similar as `int * f1 = malloc(sizeof(int)); f2 = f1; free(f1);` then using `f2` causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough, both will be closed and both will point to a closed file.

Assigning `f2=f1` doesn't do anything magical (increasing a reference count or duplicating descriptors).

Comment: Just being curious. Seeing that f1, f2 are pointers, why should anything special happen at all? No function should be able to distinguish between them, since passing a pointer as a parameter in fact does a copy of the given pointer. Or is there smth special about FILE* ?

Comment: @iolo That's right! There is nothing special about them and (in C) there's no way anything can happen under the hood just by saying `f2 = f1`.